# Alcatel 3G Modem X600 - Kernel Panic on resuming

Tags: kernel-panic, cellular-data

Alcatel X600 is a 3G USB dongle. It worked well with the two previous OS X version. I have updated and am using OS X 10, El Capitan. The USB dongle works well without any problem but when it awakes from sleep, it goes into Kernel panic. So, I want to devise a solution to the above problem and want to take some suggestions before I try it. No firmware updates are available, I already had a look.

Proposal: The proposal is to restart the drivers i.e., to unload before sleeping and reload on resuming if the dongle is present.

Problems: 
1.The dongle itself comes with some drivers but i am unable to find them where they are installed. 
2. How to check in a bash script if a USB device is present?

Thanks for your time

Comment: This problem is not any more present in the new macOS Sierra. I think they fixed it after I send them my kernel panic reports.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not any more present in the new macOS Sierra. I think they fixed it after I send them my kernel panic reports.